# codeigniter cimongo update existing information

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, sql-update

i want to update a balance field on my mongodb.

This is my code :

```
     // $this->cimongo->update("users", array('$inc' => array('balance' => -$advertiser_price)));
                //$this->cimongo->update("users", array("balance" => 'balance' - $publisher_price));
                //$this->cimongo->update("users", array("balance" => -$publisher_price));
                $this->cimongo->update("users", array("balance" => -$advertiser_price));
```

when i try this code, the field "balance" is set to -$advertiser_price
not an update balance-advertiser_price...

How can update balance to > balance - advertiser_price ?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: you are missing where clause. and there is error in your query as well

Comment: should be like this `$user_id = '1';
    $this->cimongo->where("id", $user_id);
    $this->cimongo->update("users", array("balance" => $advertiser_price));`

Comment: Hello pradeep, and thanks.
i haven't mentionned that i have $advertiser_price before..
This request works but not corectly : 
before update advetiser balance = 10
after update advertiser balance = -1 (1 is the price of the ad)
I don't understant why it not do an update, it makes a SET to new .. any idea ?
Can i do :
$this->cimongo->update("users", array("balance"+"balance" => $advertiser_price));   ?

Comment: for that first you have to select the balance from your table then subtract from it and then update the balance by user id